# WIFI disconnects itself

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, windows-8, wireless-networking

Having problem with wifi adapter on my laptop. When i connect my laptop to wifi it works for some time and disconnects itself. When im trying to connect again i cant. I had Windows XP, and i thought that it is problem of OS. So i changed OS for Windows 8, but problem  was again. I read that OS can disconnect WIFI for energy economy, and i disabled checkbox in WIRED adapter that allows to disable adapter. But it didn`t worked. Also i have one more laptop that using this wifi and it works perfectly.
Laptop model Dell Latitude D610. Network adapter Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2915ABG

Comment: Your description of the problem is vague and omits details. You say it "disconnects itself" -- but from what? Can you still reach the router when it's "disconnected"? You also say that when you try to reconnect you "cant", but you don't say why. How are you trying to reconnect and what exactly happens? Also, what does resolve the problem?

Comment: Why did you "disable checkbox in WIRED adapter" while you're having problems with your "WIRELESS" adapter? Try to do the same with the "Wireless"-adapter.

Comment: laptop disconects from the wifi router. then i'm trying to connect to the wifi connection windows writes me that it cant to conect to the network

Comment: there is no such tab as "energy control" like in wired connection

Answer (score 0):

What model of laptop do you use and what's the model of it's network card? As of me it looks like it's the problem with drivers, I'd try to update them to the newest ones from the producer (not those given by the Windows Update)

Comment: when I used Windows XP there were original drivers and it didnt worked corectly

Comment: @OlegDobra did you check the device setting from the device manager?  And in there the Power Management ? Its definately related to power saver

Comment: How Should i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For an Intel wireless adapter you can find some info on [this page](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-032513.htm) about setting the Power Managment. Go trough all these settings to make sure they are all on "Maximum Performance".

In the Advanced options of the Wireless adapter you need to set `Power Managment` to `0`.

For Windows 7/8 the user interface is different. The Power Management configuration is no longer accessed through the Device Manager, but rather through the `Control Panel` `Power Options`.

[image: Power Options]